# How to toggle using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an accordion, and I'm able able to open on each click, but how can I close it back again?

HTML:

```
<ul class="accordion">
<li id="one" class="files">
        <a href="#one">Calendar 1<span>10</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Sub Menu<span>1</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<li id="two" class="mail">
        <a href="#two">Calendar 2<span>20</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Sub Menu<span>2</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<li id="three" class="cloud">
        <a href="#three">Calendar 3<span>30</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Sub Menu<span>3</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<li id="four" class="sign">
        <a href="#four">Calendar 4</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Sub Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Store variables
  var accordion_head = $('.accordion > li > a'),
      accordion_body = $('.accordion li > .sub-menu');

  // Open the first tab on load
  accordion_head.first().addClass('active').next().slideDown('normal');

  // Click function
  accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {
    // Disable header links
    event.preventDefault();

    // Show and hide the tabs on click
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
      $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fuuLh494/

Comment: Please put the JavaScript code you wrote in your question itself. A JSFiddle link is a nice addition, but we're aiming for self-contained questions on Stack Overflow. Right now, if JSFiddle goes offline for some reason, your question won't be able to stand on its own.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to explicitly check for active class occurence and then do add/remove decision of class. You can achieve this with `toggleClass`:

```
accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
  $('.sub-menu').not($(this).next()).slideUp('normal').prev().removeClass('active');
  $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0ydhjnpx/2/)**

Comment: Can I suggest one amendment? Change `$('.sub-menu').not($(this).next()).slideUp('normal');` to `$('.sub-menu').not($(this).next()).slideUp('normal').prev().removeClass('active');`.  I like the way your solution auto collapses the previous accordian but I think it should remove the active class as it's no longer open. Just a thought. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/0ydhjnpx/1/) is your fiddle updated.

Comment: @War10ck: that is much better. please feel free to update my answer :)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Awesome. Thanks a bunch. It's been edited.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `if` completely, and use both `slideToggle` and `toggleClass`:

```
$(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fuuLh494/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
        //accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
        $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
       //accordion_head.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
```

See the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9ev31v6w/

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do with a tutorial is learn, and not copy&paste without read the code. It's as simple as this:

http://jsfiddle.net/fuuLh494/1/

I add `else` statement at the end of the script:

```
      else {
            $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace all instances of `addClass` with `toggleClass` and remove the condition of if class is active.

We are trying to remove the class when the class is already added using `toggleClass()` and don't need any if condition block.

```
accordion_head.first().toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('normal'); // Changed
if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active') { } // Removed
$(this).toggleClass('active'); // Changed
```

[**Working JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/fuuLh494/2/)

Comment: Yup, there are trollers around the web :D